# How to calculate $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma\left(n-x\sqrt n\right)}\frac{1}{n^{x\sqrt n}}\,$ given that $x\in\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, gamma-function

How to calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma\left(n-x\sqrt n\right)}\frac{1}{n^{x\sqrt n}}\,$ given that $x\in\mathbb R$?

I know that it should be $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$, but I don't know the steps.

Comment: Use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Take logarithms; then Stirling's approximation (which must be or become your friend)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Post you comment as an asnwer, I will mark it as correct. Also one will need to use $log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\omicron(x^3)$.

Comment: What you must do is $\log(n!)-\log((n-x \sqrt n)!)-x \sqrt n \log(n)$ and apply Stirling for $\log(m!)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $(n-x\sqrt n)!$...? Factorial is usually defined for positive integers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Yes, that is what I have done, but after a while, you also must use the series expansion of the logarithm. Please post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: just take the integer part, as $n\rightarrow\infty$ that will cause less and less error.

Comment: @HodossySzabolcs Then you should edit your post to clarify that you mean $\lfloor n-x\sqrt n\rfloor !$ rather than $(n-x\sqrt n)!$ (So that users reading your question know what is actually being asked.)

Comment: @HodossySzabolcs More common would be the interpretation of $y!$ as $\Gamma(y+1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider $$A_n=\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma\left(n-x\sqrt n\right)}\,\frac{1}{n^{x\sqrt n}}$$ Take logarithms $$\log(A_n)=\log\big(\Gamma(n)\big)-\log\big(\Gamma\left(n-x\sqrt n\right)\big)-x \sqrt n \log(n)$$ Now, use [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) $$\log\big(\Gamma(z)\big) \sim (z-\frac 12)\log( z) - z + \frac12\log(2\pi) $$ Applying it, we then have $$\log(A_n)\sim -x\sqrt{n} +\left(-x\sqrt{n} +n-\frac{1}{2}\right) \log (n)+\left(x\sqrt{n}
   -n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \log \left(n-x\sqrt{n} \right)$$ Now, rewrite $$\log \left(n-x\sqrt{n}\right)=\log(n)+\log(1-\frac x {\sqrt n})\sim \log(n)-\frac x {\sqrt n}-\frac{x^2}{2n}$$ Replacing in the previous expression, after simplifications, $$\log(A_n)\sim -\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{n}}-\left(\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{1}{2}\right) x^2-\frac{x^3}{2
   \sqrt{n}}$$ So, for infinitely large values of $n$, $\log(A_n)\sim -\frac{x^2}2$